# java based programming challenges

Tags: java, puzzle

Is there any website which provides core java based programming challenges that tests programming logic?

Comment: Java is large, which part of the core?

Comment: Try this http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/

Comment: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/

Comment: My favorite- http://java4732.blogspot.in/2015/06/programming-challenges.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)

It's not Java specific, but a good Programming Challenge site for any language.

Comment: You can find many more here- http://java4732.blogspot.in/2015/06/programming-challenges.html

Answer (score 14):

The following sites have some good programming challenges. There is nothing like a challenge based on a language. Hope these links help you.

[Top coder](http://www.topcoder.com/)
[Spoj](http://www.spoj.pl/)
[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)
[Code Chef](http://www.codechef.com/)

Answer (score 14):

I add [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/) to the sites mentioned here. And project Euler get also my recommendation.

Comment: I just lost an hour of my day on CodingBat...and I'm a figgin' .NET developer.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Had the chance to try this out last week and I had a blast with it!

Comment: Yes! Robocode rules! There is a similar project (also from IBM) that involves car racing. It's also pretty cool.

Comment: Could you please provide a link?

Comment: http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/coderally

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook Careers website has [a dozen or so programming puzzles](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php) which can be solved in a variety of languages, Java 1.5 among them.

I highly recommend giving these a shot, some of the problems are deceptively difficult and test your algorithm knowledge/design much more than anything specific to any one language.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :) http://projecteuler.net/ when you solve the current problem you can compare your solution to others.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate